# AWS ECS container can't specify a region

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

### First, I use the server environment:

- sever: django + nginx + uwsgi
- cloud: docker + AWS ECS
- logging: AWS CloudWatch log service + watchtower third party app

### This is project code

https://github.com/byunghyunpark/django-log-test

### Question

I am using the django watchtower third party app to use the AWS Cloudwatch log service. If I set the logging handler to watchtower and upload the docker image to the ECS service and run the task, it will still return 500 error.

500 error If you check the log

`/tmp/uwsgi.log`

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
DEBUG = False
DEV = False
TEST = False
LMS_MESSAGE = False
STATIC_S3 = True
DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL = INFO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 558, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 731, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/watchtower/__init__.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.cwl_client = (boto3_session or boto3).client("logs")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 83, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 836, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 70, in create_client
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 224, in _get_client_args
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/args.py", line 45, in get_client_args
    endpoint_url, is_secure, scoped_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/args.py", line 103, in compute_client_args
    service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 297, in resolve
    service_name, region_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 122, in construct_endpoint
    partition, service_name, region_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 135, in _endpoint_for_partition
    raise NoRegionError()
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mysite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 795, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 566, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'watchtower': You must specify a region.
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 22)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 33, cores: 1)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/1] 123.212.195.148 () {40 vars in 738 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 10:43:13 2017] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/2] 123.212.195.148 () {40 vars in 756 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 10:43:13 2017] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/3] 54.167.97.82 () {36 vars in 515 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 11:22:42 2017] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/4] 91.196.50.33 () {38 vars in 613 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 12:03:20 2017] GET /testproxy.php => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/5] 123.212.195.148 () {40 vars in 738 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 14:01:04 2017] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/6] 123.212.195.148 () {40 vars in 756 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 14:01:04 2017] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/7] 123.212.195.148 () {42 vars in 769 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 14:06:48 2017] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/8] 123.212.195.148 () {44 vars in 809 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 14:06:48 2017] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/9] 123.212.195.148 () {42 vars in 769 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 14:06:49 2017] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/10] 123.212.195.148 () {44 vars in 809 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 14:06:49 2017] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 33|app: -1|req: -1/11] 123.212.195.148 () {42 vars in 769 bytes} [Mon Jun  5 14:06:49 2017] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

task IAM role was assigned to administrator when task definition was created.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the container still does not talk to credentials.

If I change logging handler to default(console), the nginx server will work normally. If I run a docker conatiner with `docker run -v $ HOME / .aws: /root/.aws --rm -it -p 9090: 80 image_name` in local, nginx will work normally and the logging will work normally do in Cloudwatch log service.

Only in ECS environment fails authentication.

Do I need to do other settings besides IAM roles?

Answer (score 0):

I do not like this..
As a temporary resolution,

when I build docker, I passed the credentials information with the Dockerfile ARG variable. and I removed Task IAM.

Dockerfile's code like this

```
ARG         AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG         AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG         AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

ENV         AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} \
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} \
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
```